# Typescript/Dojo Use AMD to load a data file

Tags: dojo, typescript

Typescript newbie here. I have a Dijit Widget that I'm trying to convert into Typescript.
It obvisously lives inside an AMD module.

[Bryan Forbe's .d.ts files](https://github.com/bryanforbes/dojo-typescript) give me most declarations I need to turn my former

```
define(['dojo/_base/declare'], ...
```

style imports into idiomatic

```
import dojoDeclare = require('dojo/_base/declare');
```

As for dependencies that don't have their .d.ts yet, I suppose that having the following hack in a global context should be enough to shunt the type system and opt-in smoothly, isn't it ?

```
declare module 'dojox/gfx' {
    var gfx: any;
    export = gfx;
}
```

However loading widget templates or internationalization data files just won't get there. I can't simply write

```
declare module 'dojo/text!./templates/Widget.html' {
    var html: string;
    export = html;
}
import template = require('dojo/text!./templates/Widget.html');
```

I suspect that the string format is illegal for Typescript. But hey, that's the string I need.

A way to circumvent this would be falling back on Dojo's AMD loader, using `require` and callbacks and promises and stuff *inside* of what would already be an AMD `define` block. This would kick me right into asynchronous sadomasochism.

**Therefore I'm wondering : is there's a way to use the host's AMD mechanism seamlessly without having Typescript go for its own checks ?**

---

*Edited after the first posted answer.*

As suggested by Basarat, I've declared a dependency with

```
/// <amd-dependency path='dojo/text!./templates/Widget.html' />
```

This indeed adds the wanted file to `define`'s dependency list.
It doesn't, however, provide a way to get the module's return value into a callback parameter.

[Colin Snover's Definitive Typescript Guide](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2013/12/31/definitive-guide-to-typescript/) goes this way

```
var template:string = require('dojo/text!./templates/Widget.html');
```

This shall work fine in every case, since by the time the callback body is running the dependency will already have been loaded, now appearing in `define`'s list thanks to the `amd-dependency` statement.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/schungx/Dojo-TypeScript

Comment: There is a way to handle plugin's and `dojo/text!` that is sort of simple (as in not-as-complicated-as-it-normally-requires)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/// <amd-dependency path="jquery"/>
```

This adds jquery to the define call without any type checks.

Comment: Hi Basarat, and thanks for the hint, I didn't know that one.

The comment I'd like to write would be a tad long, therefore I'll edit the initial question with it.